# auto-morphisms on von Neumann algebras

Tags: functional-analysis, von-neumann-algebras

Let $J$ be an $*$-automorphism on a II$_1$-factor with a faithful normal tracial state $\tau$. Since $J$ preserves the identity, it follows that $\tau(J\cdot)$ is also a faithful normal tracial state. By the uniqueness of this tracial state, we obtain that $\tau(J\cdot )=\tau(\cdot)$. Hence, $J$ preserves the traces.

For $B(h)$, all automorphisms are inner, and therefore, they preserve traces.

I would like to ask whether the statement is also true for the II$_\infty$ factor? That is, can I say that all $*$-automorphisms on a II$_\infty$ factor preserves traces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Take for instance $M=R\otimes B(H)$, with $R$ the hyperfinite II$_1$-factor. Normalize the trace $\tau$ so that $\tau(1\otimes E_{11})=1$. We can write $M$ as $M=R\otimes M_2(\mathbb C)\otimes B(H)$. Let $\theta$ be an isomorphism between $R\otimes M_2(\mathbb C)$ and $R$, and define $J=\theta\otimes\operatorname{id}$. Consider $p=1\otimes (E_{11}+E_{22})\otimes E_{11}$. Then $Jp$ is the identity in $R$, and
$$
\tau(p)=2,\qquad \tau(Jp)=1. 
$$

Comment: Many thx Martin

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Comment: Can we find a type II$_\infty$ factor $M$ and a $*$ automorphism $J$ such that $J$ is the identity on the center of $M$  and $\tau\circ J\neq \tau$?

Comment: If $M$ is a factor then its centre is trivial. Any automorphism preserves the scalars, so any $J$ with $\tau\circ J\ne\tau$ will foot the bill.

Comment: Professor Argerami, I wonder whether there exist papers or reference books discussing the above  problems ?

Comment: Not sure. You give a single problem which can be seen as an exercise. I wouldn't know how to frame it.